Docker libssl.so.3: cannot open shared object file
I've been trying to setup my pipeline, however I cannot get the container to run. Get the following error no matter what I try
/direct_server: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I don't have any openssl dependencies.
Ive tried musl with scratch and same error.
What am I doing wrong here?
Dockerfile
# Use the Rust image for building
#FROM rust:latest as builder
FROM rust:bookworm as builder

# Set offline mode to prevent runtime preparation
ENV SQLX_OFFLINE=true

# Install necessary dependencies and git
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libssl-dev \
    pkg-config \
    build-essential \
    git && \
    apt-get clean

# Use secrets to pass GitHub token securely
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=RDX_GITHUB_TOKEN \
    git clone https://$(cat /run/secrets/RDX_GITHUB_TOKEN)@github.com/acct/infrastructure.git infrastructure && \
    git clone https://$(cat /run/secrets/RDX_GITHUB_TOKEN)@github.com/acct/database.git database

# Copy the source code
COPY . .

# Copy the `.sqlx` folder (generated by cargo sqlx prepare)
COPY .sqlx .sqlx

# Update paths in Cargo.toml to use relative paths
RUN sed -i 's|{ path = "../infrastructure" }|{ path = "infrastructure" }|' Cargo.toml
RUN sed -i 's|{ path = "../database" }|{ path = "database" }|' Cargo.toml

# Build the Rust binary
RUN cargo build --release

# Minimal runtime image
FROM debian:bookworm-slim

# Install necessary runtime libraries (including libssl3) and verify installation
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libssl3 \
    libssl-dev \
    pkg-config \
    ca-certificates && \
    apt-get clean && \
    ldconfig && \
    ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3

# Copy the built binary from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder /target/release/direct_server /direct_server

# Set the entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT ["/direct_server"]


You might try docker run --rm --entrypoint ldd your-image /direct_server to see the C shared-library dependencies; what does this tell you?  (This becomes less awkward if you change ENTRYPOINT to CMD in the last line; you also might consider putting the binary into a normal binary path, like /usr/local/bin/direct_server.)
